# UART - wrong symbols on PC

Tags: serial-port, embedded, uart, ftdi

1. I'm writing a simple program to transmit data from the MCU to the PC.
2. I'm using FTDI cable to achieve that.
3. Data that I'm sending is string digits from 0 to 9 (0x30 to 0x39 as ascii codes).
4. Both the MCU and the PC terminal are configured to 9600 kbps, 8 bits, no parity, no flow control, one stop bit.
5. When the data transferred from the MCU to the PC - symbols are wrong.
6. When TX and RX lines of the MCU are both connected to each other - I can see, that all symbols that were sent, were received by the MCU.
7. When TX and RX lines of the FTDI cable (connected to the PC) are connected to each other - all symbols that were sent from the PC terminal were received by the PC.

I cannot understand what can be wrong in sending data from the MCU to the PC.

Please, help!

Comment: Even though you way both are set up with the same baud rate, the behavior you're seeing indicates a mismatch. What happens when you send characters from the PC to the MCU?

Comment: Use a scope to verify the signals.

Comment: You say `5. When the data transferred from the MCU to the PC - symbols are wrong.` - how are they wrong? Are bits shifted? Scrambled? Does it seem random?

Comment: This might depend on the receive methods on the PC, of which you give no details. Do you *always* receive with a terminal emulator, or does your real code use some kind of polled (not interrupt) solution? In the PC loop-back test using a "terminal" you are probably typing chars from a keyboard, so that might not be a realistic comparison with the transmitter code at the MCU, since if your *actual* PC code polls for serial input, it may miss bytes.

Comment: Or, perhaps when the MCU transmits up to speed there is a flow control problem, although 9600 baud isn't particularly fast. You never mentioned anything about connecting RTS/CTS in your loopback tests. When the MCU transmits up to speed to a terminal, you might need flow control enabled (and wired).

Comment: Try to post the MCU serial init functions, and tell us which MCU you're using.

Comment: Hello, I found the solution. Thanks a lot! It was problem in USB to UART adapter cable.
The chip is EFM32G890F128
I'm using Low Power Uart.
Here the code:
void LEUART0_setup(void) {    
    LEUART_Init_TypeDef leuart = LEUART_INIT_DEFAULT;
    leuart.baudrate = 9600;
    leuart.databits = leuartDatabits8;
    leuart.enable = leuartEnable;
    leuart.parity = leuartNoParity;
    leuart.stopbits = leuartStopbits1;    
    LEUART_Init(LEUART0, &leuart);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is more simple than I thought.
For my previous applications I used the ATC-810 cable (USB-to-UART, FT232BL chip).
At the past it worked, but now for some reason it doesn't works. New drivers from FTDI, may be...
When I took the TTL-232R-3V3 cable - all data that I'm sending from the MCU I'm receiving on the PC!

Thanks a lot for trying to help!!

Answer (score 4):

The symptoms you describe suggest a timing mismatch between the PC and the MCU.  UART serial comms can tolerate a baud rate mismatch of <5% at either end.  In practice because teh PC is certainly accurate, you might get away with up to 10% in the embedded target - but that is extreme.  Either the baud rate divisor for your part is incorrectly programmed, or your system clock is inaccurate or simply not the frequency you believe it to be.  RC oscillators on some MCUs used to reduce costs can be off-nominal as bad as +/-10%.

You should verify the clock and the baud rate directly with an oscilloscope, or laboriously verify every clock setting from the PLL to the UART baud-rate generator.